# Refresh section of a page using EJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a checkbox that when pressed call a function that does a GET request. Based on the selection I want to display extra checkboxes on the same page. At the moment this is the code I have so far:

Client side

```
function selectedHouse(house)
{
   if(house.checked){
      $.get('/', {data: house.value});
   }
}
```

Server side

```
var routing = function (nav, houses) {
    router.route('/')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            var rooms = [];
            rooms = getRooms(req.query.data);
            console.log(rooms);

            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Independent cleaner',
                nav: nav,
                houses: houses,
                roomsForHouse: rooms
            });
        });
    return router;
};
```

The first time the page loads, it loads with the correct title, nav and houses. When the function is executed on client side, I get back the related rooms for the house and I'm trying to populate the roomsForHouse variable which I'm displaying on the view.

The problem is that the view doesn't render the roomsForHouse variable. So the GET request is called once the page loads and a second time when the function executes. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit more complex. You'll need to use ajax for this. EJS is server side templates (as you are using them) so you'll want to use jQuery to make the call and update your already rendered page.

**Server**
Your server will need a route that delivers JSON data. Right now you are rendering the entire page. So:

```
app.get('/rooms/:id',  function (req, res) {

  // Get the house info from database using the id as req.params.id
  ...

  // Return the data
  res.json({
    rooms: 2
    ...
  });
});
```

**Client**

Using jQuery make a call to your json route once the user selects the house.

```
function selectedHouse(house)
{
   if(house.checked){
      // Pass some identifier to use for your database
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/rooms/' + house.id,
        success: function(data) {
          // Update the element - easiet is to use EJS to make sure each house has an id/class with the id in it
          // Given an ID of 2 this says find the div with class house_2 and updates its div with class room to the number of rooms
          $('.house_' + house.id + ' .rooms').text(data.rooms);  
      });
   }
}
```

This is more of pseudo code then anything but should put you on the right track.

Comment: Your solution should work and I like it. I think the question is now, am I doing it correctly ? If you would have started from zero how would you have implemented. It's a pet project of mine so there is no real impact if I start from scratch. I still want to use node.js and express.

Comment: Also you answered my question so I'm going to mark it as solved, although I would like to see how you would have done it.

Comment: You're doing it right. I would have my `/` route render the index page with a list of all your houses from the database then using the ID of each you can fetch the rooms on demand. So 2 routes. Of course it depends on your actual data. Traditionally one might fetch a paginated list of houses (just the basics for each house) followed by a detailed view for each (rooms plus all the other details). But the gist of it is correct. You are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

res.render can't rerender view, for refresh page in second time you need use javascript to replace html. This is not good solution

```js
$.get("/",function(html){   
  document.open();    
  document.write(html);
  document.close();    
});
```

For better you should use another router to render DOM you want to change

Comment: Can you provide a basic example of what the client code should be and the server side code